# ack search for content within Smarty TPL template files

Tags: search, smarty, case-insensitive, ack

Is it possible to use `ack` to search for content within Smarty template files (.tpl)?

At the moment I can only search within the cached version of these templates, which themselves are PHP files.

If I do a case-insensitive `ack` search like this below this is what is returned:

```
[crmpicco@dev dev_crmpicco]$ ack -i select\ the\ course
cache/templates/gb/%%9B^9B3^9B37B147%%course.tpl.php
48:                             <p><label>Select the course:</label></p>
64:                             <p><label>Select the course:</label></p>
83:                             <p><label>Select the course:</label></p>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like what you're asking is "How do I get ack 1.x to recognize .tpl as a valid filetype?"

What you want is to put `--type-set=smarty=.tpl` on the command line or in the ACK_OPTIONS environment variable or in your .ackrc file.  Then you can say things like "ack --smarty foo" and it will only search smarty files.

You probably also want to use `--ignore-dir=cache` so ack doesn't search in your cache directory.

Case sensitivity is unrelated to the issues here.

Comment: I tried `ack --type-add=smarty=.tpl`, but no luck: `ack: --type-add: Type "smarty" does not exist, creating with ".tpl" ...`

Comment: My mistake, it's `--type-set`.  `--type-add` adds extensions to an existing type.  But still, you should have ack selecting .tpl files.  Do an `ack -f` to see what files ack is selecting to be searched.

Comment: For some reason I can't seem to add Smarty templates to my `.ackrc` file with that command either. This is what i'm doing: `ack --type-set=smarty=.tpl` and i'm getting an error: `ack: No regular expression found.` Is this expected?

Comment: You didn't specify a search string.  You just said "know about this file type for the duration of this search", but gave ack nothing to search for.  If you're still having problems, please post to either the ack-users mailing list.

Comment: Apologies for any confusion, but I was under the impression that using the `--type-set=smarty=.tpl` switch I would be _permanently_ adding Smarty (or .tpls) as valid files to search. Is this not the case? If I want to search Smarty do I have to specify this switch every time?

Comment: Yes, `--type-set` and `--type-add` are not permanent, just like no other switch like `-i` is permanent.  Yes, you have to specify that switch every time.  Fortunately, since your ~/.ackrc gets added to the command line each time, adding them to your ~/.ackrc is effectively specifying them every time.

Comment: Many thanks, `ack --type-set=smarty=.tpl searchterm` does indeed work. However, is it possible to search _only_ on .tpl files as this includes **all** files, not just Smarty templates.

Comment: Once you define "tpl" as a type, then you can use the `--tpl` and `--notpl` flags.  In your case `ack --type-set=smarty=.tpl --tpl searchterm`.  Or, put the `--type-set` in your ~/.ackrc and then you can use `--tpl` whenever you want.

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't clear...

If you want to find filename of template, which is filled with some content after render, here is it (wtih bold):

> cache/templates/gb/%%9B^9B3^9B37B147%%**course.tpl**.php

Comment: If you re-read my question you will see I have asked if it is possible to search for _content_ within Smarty templates. I'm not looking for filenames.